# Server 2022 - Maui app with net .7 is not working

Tags: .net, maui

I installed Maui app on server 2019 with this command and its works but on server 2022 its not work:

dotnet publish -f net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -c Release -p:WindowsPackageType=None -p:WindowsAppSDKSelfContained=true /p:PackageCertificateThumbprint="c01ba45666762f3615cf6813aeb4dc4b1919541d"

I also installed .NET7 on server 2019 + 2022 :

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download - .NET 7.0

Why is not work on 2022 ?
With NET 6 it works on server 2019+2022!!!

The error:
[image]

Comment: On Microsoft Q&A @danies8 said this started working after his IT department updated the configuration on their servers. Likely the servers had been missing a dependency the app relied on.